# Entity Framework- Cannot reference entity context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbcontext

Context:

```
public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
   public EntityContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
      {

      }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
          var cascadeTables = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
           .SelectMany(foreignKeysTables => foreignKeysTables.GetForeignKeys())
           .Where(foreignKeysTables => !foreignKeysTables.IsOwnership &&
                  foreignKeysTables.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

         foreach (var table in cascadeTables)
         {
             table.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
         }

         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     }

    DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

Saving into the database using the context:

```
using (var context = new EntityContext()) //error on EntityContext()
{
     context.Account.Add(acc); //error on Account because EntityContext can't be referenced
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I can't reference the context because there's a parameter needed for it (DbContextOptions options), how can I get past it so I can save my Account instance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure DbContextOptions since DbContext requires DbContextOptions to work correctly. DbContextOptions contains information such as database provider and connection string.

It can be configured in below ways:

**1) When using a Dependency Injection Container**

If you are using default Dependency Injection Container in ASP.Net Core, you can add below code in Startup.cs inside the method ConfigureServices.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        // ...other service registration 
        services.AddDbContext<EntityContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

and in appsettings.json, you need to define the connection string:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=servername;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Then, Dependency Injection Container will provide options to the Entity Context when the object is created.

```
public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
   public EntityContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
      {

      }

      .....
}
```

Then, you can use in your class as follows:

```
public class AccountRepository
{
    private readonly EntityContext context;    

    public AccountRepository(EntityContext entityContext)
    {
            this.context = entityContext;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
         context.Account.Add(acc); 
         context.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```

---

**2) OnConfiguring option - Initialize the DbContextOptions within the context itself (When Dependency Injection Container is not used):**

```
public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }

    .....
}
```

Then, in your class, you can instantiate context without passing arguments:

```
using (var context = new EntityContext()) 
{
     context.Account.Add(acc); 
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

---

**3) Pass DbContextOptions as constructor argument when instantiating Context (When Dependency Injection Container is not used):**

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EntityContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

using (var context = new EntityContext(optionsBuilder.Options)) 
{
     context.Account.Add(acc); 
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the third solution is what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency injection (constructor injection) with an IOC container like,

```
public class YourClass {
    private readonly EntityContext context; 
    public YourClass(EntityContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void YourMethod(){
       context.Account.Add(acc);
       context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

> Most popular IOC containers,
>
> - Unity Container
> - Castle Windsor
> - NInject
> - Structure Map

You need to specify with IOC container how to create the instance of EntityContext  like singleton, scoped or transient. Something like this;

```
var container = new YourContainer();
container.Register<DbContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your context in DI container, then it can be injected to any object's constructor you need. And you won't need to construct context manually each time.
[See more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!